# If $\|S\|<\sin\frac{\pi}{2n}$ then $\|P(I-S)^ku\|\neq 0$ for all $k=0,\ldots,n$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I want to show the following:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $S:H\to H$ be a bounded operator such that 
$$\|S\|<\sin\frac{\pi}{2n}.$$
Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a closed subspace of $H$ and $$u_k:=(I-S)^ku,\;\;\;\;\text{for}\;\;\;k=0,\ldots,n\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;u\in\mathcal{L}\setminus\{0\}.$$ 
Prove that
$$\|Pu_k\|\neq 0\;\;\;\text{for}\;\;\;k=0,\ldots,n,$$
where $P$ denotes the orthogonal projection on $\mathcal{L}$.

An idea:

For $k=0$ is clear because $Pu_0=Pu=u\in\mathcal{L}\setminus\{0\}$.

For $k=1$, suppose that $Pu_1=0$ then $u_1\in\mathcal{L}^\perp$ and

\begin{align*}
    0&=\langle u_0,u_1\rangle=\langle u_0,u_0\rangle-\langle u_0,Su_0\rangle\\
&\geq \|u_0\|^2-\|S\|\|u_0\|^2\\
&>\left(1-\sin\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)\|u_0\|^2>0
\end{align*}
which is not posible. So, $\|Pu_1\|\neq 0$.

For $k>2$, I don't know how to continue. Can someone give me an idea? Thanks.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: I am reading the article "Geometry of higher order realtive spectrum of linear operator in Hilbert spaces" by Eugene Shargorodsky. In Theorem 5.2 he shows that if $T$ is a bounded operator then $$\left(\sin\left(\frac{π}{2n}\right)\right)^{-1}\|T\|$$
is a bound of the $n$-th order spectrum $\mathrm{Spec}_n(T,\mathcal{L})$ for any closed linear subespace $\mathcal{L}$ of $H$. In his proof, he divides by the quantity $\|Pu_k\|$ but I do not know why this quantity is $\neq 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your condition that $\| S\|<\sin\frac{\pi}{2n}$ implies that the angle between
$u_{{k+1}}$ and $u_{k}$ is less than $\pi/2n$, for $k=0,...,n-1$. Therefore the angle
between $u=u_0$ and $u_{k}$ is $<\pi/2$ for $k=1,...,n$. Since $u\in L$, $u_1,...,u_n$ cannot be orthogonal to $L$ that is $Pu_k\neq 0$.

Comment: Nice solution, I wonder whether there is a proof without using properties of angles. By the way, the triangle inequality for angles is not straighforward and I found the original paper by Rao in the web. Any other source?

Comment: Triangle property for angles is easy. Since we are dealing with finitely many vectors, it is enough to consider their span, which is a finite dimensional space. Now the angle between vectors is the spherical distance on the unit sphere between the endpoints of the corresponding unit vectors.

Comment: You are right, I see. Then I wonder why there are papers on the subject!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do not underestand why the angle between $u_k$ and $u_{k+1}$ has to be less than $\frac{\pi}{2n}$. Also, if $H$ is a complex Hilbert space. How do I underestand the angle between two vectors in this span?

Comment: The angle is $\arccos$ of (the absolute value of the dot product, divided by the product of the norms).

Comment: With this definition, for the angle $\theta_k$ between $u_k$ and $u_{k+1}$ I did the following estimate:
$$\theta_k=\arccos\left(\frac{|\langle u_k,u_{k+1}\rangle|}{\|u_k\|\|u_{k+1}\|}\right)\leq \arccos\left(\frac{1−\sin\frac{π}{2n}}{1+\sin\frac{π}{2n}}\right)$$
but
$$\arccos\left(\frac{1−\sin\frac{π}{2n}}{1+\sin\frac{π}{2n}}\right)>\frac{π}{2n}.$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Another question: Is the angle between $u_0$ and $u_k$ less than $\pi$ or less than $\pi/2$?. Thank you for your reply.